# Yarn in Aazon EC2 with whirr

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hadoop-yarn, apache-whirr

i am trying to configue  Yarn 2.2.0 with whirr in Amazon EC2. however I am having some problems. I have modified the whirr services to support yarn 2.2.0. As a result I am able to start the jobs and run them successfully. however I am facing n issue in tracking the job progress.

```
 mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1317)) - Running job: job_1397996350238_0001
2014-04-20 21:57:24,544 INFO  [main] mapred.ClientServiceDelegate (ClientServiceDelegate.java:getProxy(270)) - Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history server
java.io.IOException: Job status not available 
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.updateStatus(Job.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.isComplete(Job.java:599)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.monitorAndPrintJob(Job.java:1327)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1289)
    at com.zetaris.hadoop.seek.preprocess.PreProcessorDriver.executeJobs(PreProcessorDriver.java:112)
    at com.zetaris.hadoop.seek.JobToJobMatchingDriver.executePreProcessJob(JobToJobMatchingDriver.java:143)
    at com.zetaris.hadoop.seek.JobToJobMatchingDriver.executeJobs(JobToJobMatchingDriver.java:78)
    at com.zetaris.hadoop.seek.JobToJobMatchingDriver.executeJobs(JobToJobMatchingDriver.java:43)
    at com.zetaris.hadoop.seek.JobToJobMatchingDriver.main(JobToJobMatchingDriver.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212
```

I tried Debugginh the problem is with the ApplicationMaster. It has an hostname and rpc port , in which the hostname is the internal hostname which can only be resolved from within the amazon network. Idealy it should have been a public Amazon DNs name. however I could'nt set it yet. I tried setting parameters like

yarn.nodemanager.hostname
yarn.nodemanager.address

But I couldnt find any change in the ApplicationMaster's hostname or port they are still the private amazon internal hostname. Am I missing anything. Or should I change the /etc/hosts in all node manager nodes so that node managers start with the public address..
But that will be an overkill right.Or is there any way I can configure the ApplicationMaster to take the public ip.So that I can Remotely track the progress

I am doing this all because I need to submit the jobs remotely.I am not willing to compromise this feature. Anyone out there who an guide me

I was successful in configuring the historyserver and I am able to access then from the remote client. I used the configuration to do it.

mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address

When i debugged I find the

```
 MRClientProtocol MRClientProxy = null;
      try {
        MRClientProxy = getProxy();
        return methodOb.invoke(MRClientProxy, args);
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        // Will not throw out YarnException anymore
        LOG.debug("Failed to contact AM/History for job " + jobId + 
            " retrying..", e.getTargetException());
        // Force reconnection by setting the proxy to null.
        realProxy = null;
```

proxy failing to connect because of the private address . And above code snipped is from ClientServiceDelegate

Comment: I have exactly the same problem when running hadoop in docker. Have you been able to find a solution?

Comment: @Honza : I'm also trying to do the same in Docker. Did you get anywhere with it in the end/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to avoid the issue. Rather than solve this. The problem is with the resolution of ip outside the cloud environment.

Initially I tried updating the whirr-yarn source to make use of public ip for configurations rather than private ip. But still There where issues.So I gave up the task.

What I finally did was to start job form the cloud environment itself. rther than from a host outside the cloud infrastructure. Hope somebody found a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Solved by adding following lines in `mapred-site.yml`. It move's your staging directory from default tmp directory to your home directory where your have permission.

```
  <property>
    <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.staging-dir</name>
    <value>/user</value>
  </property>
```

In addition to this, you need to create a history directory on hdfs:

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /user/history
hdfs dfs -chmod -R 1777 /user/history
hdfs dfs -chown mapred:hadoop /user/history
```

I found this [link](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-7-x/topics/cdh_ig_yarn_cluster_deploy.html#topic_11_4_6) quite useful for configuring a Hadoop cluster.

Answer (score -1):

```
conf.set("mapreduce.jobhistory.address", "hadoop3.hwdomain:10020");
conf.set("mapreduce.jobhistory.intermediate-done-dir", "/mr-history/tmp");
conf.set("mapreduce.jobhistory.done-dir", "/mr-history/done");
```

Comment: Please describe more about your answer.